How are the default version of dependencies for an Android project determined?
What criteria are used to set the versions of the libraries that are automatically added to the dependencies when creating an Android project?
like that
dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.8.6")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}

I tried the following, but the version of the newly created project did not change:
1.  Changed the minimum library version of the project.
2.  Changed the AGP (Android Gradle Plugin Version).

Why I was curious about this,  I was taking an Android development class, and despite matching the environment with the instructor, but the library versions were different when creating new Project, so causing errors. I plan to find out the reason for this and inform my classmates.
I searched through the documents, but I couldn’t find any information about this.
Thank you in advance for your help.

I have not checked it but usually newly created projects base on template files. Therefore the versions should be fixed for the used Android Studio version.

@Robert thank you for your answer, What you mean is that the template is determined depending on the Android studio version?

I would assume that the template is not "determined" but simply included in the Android Studio installation. Therefore if you want to have identical projects after creating a new project you need to install exactly identical Android Studio versions.

@Robert thankyou for your After answer but i downloaded Android Studio that instructor gave. i think we have it of same version

The Android Studio template code generator can be found in the file wizard-template.jar which is installed to Android Studio/plugins/android/lib/wizard-template.jar.
In this file JAR file you can find a lot of images used in the UI and copied into the template project as well as the Java byte code classes for generating all the files that belong to a template project.
See package com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template and sub-packages.
Therefore it is the Android Studio Version for sure that determines the file content if you create a new project from a template.
For example the version for the dependency androidx.compose:compose-bom is defined in class com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.impl.activities.common.ComposeVersionsKt:
public static final String COMPOSE_BOM_VERSION = "2024.04.01";

This is from Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1
